# How to communicate between vueJS app & symfony with Google Token?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, jwt, api-platform.com

I am implementing Google Sign in in my VueJS App and I have a few questions before starting:

1. How to create a user when a user clicks on Google sign in button?

   - Do I have to create a custom route just for that?
   - Do I have to generate a random password because it is mandatory?
2. When a user is already registered and clicks on Google Sign in.

   - Do I have to pass Google Token from Vue JS to Symfony, then with google API, verify if token is valid and generate a token from my symfony application?

If you have some good documentation, I'll take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this started, it's actually a relatively complicated functionality to implement. This is because you'll have to use custom (maybe multiple if one can both login with Google account or register to your own website) [guard authenticators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_guard_authenticators.html). Moreover, you will need to use an OAuth bundle like [KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle) or [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle).

The answer to your questions:

1. You have to create a custom route for that but you do not need to generate a random password, you can just make password nullable and add checks that it is null only for users logged in through Google (if it's not possible for you then just add something random as password). Additionally, I would propose to add a field `provider` to your User entity if you are providing both google and your own authentication. You should set this to 'google' or 'website respectively.
2. The user authentication process is being handled by Google and you are getting an access token as response that contains user's information like name, email etc, so you do not really have to worry about validating passwords etc.

[This article](https://dev.to/_mertsimsek/integrate-oauth2-for-symfony-4-360c) helps you get started with KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle.